# Overlapping tab/drop down divs - links not working - CSS or JS issue?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, hyperlink

I am editing the XHTML/CSS for a previously built module that works as a news ticker. Instead of having one scrolling list of links, I am adding tabs so that the user may click between one list of links and another. I am also adding a drop down menu that contains the list of all of the links for the corresponding tab the user is on.

I created a non-functioning template for the module to pass to the development team. All XHTML/CSS elements are present, but no JS is attached in order to make the tabs/drop down work (I am not responsible for back end code). My local example shows both the basic state of the module, as well as the state with the drop down showing. In my local example, all of the links work, both in the "zipper" part of the module and the drop down.

However, within the context of the functioning site (after back-end dev added tabbed and drop-down functionality), the links inside the zipper are not working, and the first link in the drop down (this link overlaps the zipper) is not working. By not working I mean they are clickable, the path is visible, but they do not do anything. All of the other links in the drop down work (they do not overlap the zipper part).

While I am inclined to believe that this is a JS error, I have no way of knowing this. My only experience with JS is through jQuery, and we do not use jQuery at all.

My question is - is there anything that I can do to help the situation? Does anyone see anything in my code that raises a red flag or that I can change?

They did ask me to add some lines of CSS in order to position the hidden divs off the page. I obliged, and the issue seemed to have been resolved for awhile. I then added a background image and a color change. According to the dev team this caused the issue to happen again, so I am concerned that I am missing something in my code that I horribly erred with. However, I can't be sure, as again, I have no experience with JS or what the back end team is doing.

I am mostly looking for some help as to what might be wrong with my code, how I can add or remove parts of my code in order to assist, or if my code is fine and there are in fact JS errors.

I am attaching the XHTML of the drop down state (I did not build the original module, and rebuilding the XHTML at this point is almost completely out of the question) and the CSS (for the whole module, not just the tab/drop downs).

Thank you in advance and my apologies for the long-winded question but I thought all information might be helpful.

CSS

```
.newsTickerContainer {position:relative; z-index:1;}
.newsTicker {
    display:block;
    background-color:white;
    position:relative; 
    border-bottom:1px dotted #000;
    margin-bottom:10px; height:55px;    
    line-height:25px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.newsTicker h4 {
    float:left;
    padding:0 4px 0px 8px;
    margin:0;
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.1em;
    color:#444;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

.newsTicker .nav-inline {
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    z-index:19;
    position:relative;
}

.newsTicker ul.arrows{
    margin-left:0;
    padding:0px 4px 6px 6px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10px;
    background-color:#fff;
    right:auto;
}

.newsTicker ul.arrows .next a
{
    background: url(../img/next_arrow.gif) left top no-repeat;
    margin-left: 2px;
}
.newsTicker ul.arrows .prev a
{
    background: url(../img/prev_arrow.gif) left top no-repeat;
    margin-left: 2px;
}
.newsTicker ul.arrows .prev a,
.newsTicker ul.arrows .next a
{
    width:7px;
    height:9px;
}
.newsTicker ul.arrows .next a:hover
{
    background: url(../img/next_arrow.gif) left top no-repeat;
    margin-left: 2px;
}
.newsTicker ul.arrows .prev a:hover
{
    background: url(../img/prev_arrow.gif) left top no-repeat;
    margin-left: 2px;
}

.newsTicker ul.newsItem {
    width:20000px;
    margin-left:28px;
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:0;
    top:0px;
    left:0;
    z-index:0;
}

.newsTicker ul.newsItem li {
    width:546px;
    float:left;
}

.newsTicker h3, .newsTicker .newsItem p {
    font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
}

.newsTicker .newsItem p {
    position:absolute;
    font-size:12px;
}

.newsTicker ul.newsItem, .newsTicker ul.newsItem li{ padding-top:0px; margin-top:0px;}

 .newsTicker .newsItem p a {color:#b10717; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.2em;}
 .newsTicker .zippercontent {overflow:hidden; position:relative;}

 .newsTicker div {display:block;}
 .newsTicker .zipperhead { border-bottom:1px dotted #000; position:relative; padding: 0     4px;}
 .newsTicker .zipperhead h4 {position:relative; color:#003366; font-weight:normal; padding:0 8px; cursor:pointer; top:1px}
 .newsTicker .zipperhead h4:hover {color:#003366; font-weight:bold;}
 .newsTicker .zipperhead h4.selected,.newsTicker .zipperhead h4.selected  {float:right; z-index:40; width:70px; font-size:1em; text-align:center;   }
 .newsTicker .zipperhead h4.selected a.viewlink:hover, .newsTicker .zipperhead h4.selected a.viewlink:hover {color:#709fcf;}
 .newsTicker .zipperhead h4.selected:hover {font-weight:normal;}
 .newsTicker .zipperhead h4.activetab {  background-color:#ffffff; border:1px dotted #000; border-bottom:none; color:#333333; }
.viewAllactive .newsTicker .zipperhead h4.selected {border:1px solid #ccc; background: #f4f9ff url(../img/fx-arrowdown2.jpg) no-repeat 57px -16px; border-bottom:none; z-index:30; position:relative;}
.newsTicker .topNews_panels {overflow:hidden}
.newsTicker .zipperhead h4.activetab {font-weight:bold;}
.viewAll .newsTicker .zipperhead h4.selected {color:#275475;  padding:1px 12px 0 0  ; background:url(../img/fx-arrowdown2.jpg) no-repeat 60px 11px; height:20px;} 
.newsTicker .zipperhead h4.inactivetab {top:2px; background-color:transparent;}
.viewAll h4.selected a.viewlink {color:#04233c;}
.viewAll h4.selected a.viewlink .view {display:block;}
.viewAll h4.selected a.viewlink .hide {display:none;}
.viewAllactive h4.selected a.viewlink .view {display:none;}
.viewAllactive h4.selected a.viewlink .hide {display:block;}


.viewAllactive .newstickermore a {color:#333333; font-size:1.3em; padding:0 0 4px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:none; line-height:2em;  }
.viewAllactive .newstickermore a:hover {color:#7aa2cb;}

 .viewAllactive .newstickermore {display:block; border:1px solid #ccc; background: #f4f9ff url(../img/fx-topNewsBack.jpg) no-repeat left top; padding:8px; position:absolute; top:26px; width:549px ; left:0px; z-index:20; border-top:none;}

.viewAll .newstickermore, .viewAllactive .topNews_panels, .viewAll .topNews_panels .hidden 
    {position:absolute; display:none; height:1px; overflow:hidden; z-index:-100;left:-10000px; top:-10000px;}
```

XHTML

```
<div class="newsTickerContainer scroll_container viewAll ">
        <div class=" newsTicker">
            <div class="zipperhead clearFix">
                <h4 class="activetab">Top FX News</h4>
                <h4 class="inactivetab">Top FX News</h4>
                <h4 class="selected">
                            <a href="#" class="viewlink"><span class="view">View All</span><span class="hide">Hide</span></a>
                </h4>
            </div>
           <div class="topNews_panels">
                <div id="topNews_panel_fx">
                    <div class="zippercontent" >
                        <ul class="nav-inline arrows"><li class="prev"><a href="#prev"></a></li><li class="next"><a href="#next"></a></li></ul>
                        <ul class="newsItem" >
                            <li>
                               <p><a target="_self" href="/page/top-fx-news.html#id=SBA0000905878218084517604575588140389821442">FX Video Test</a></p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                               <p><a target="_self" href="/page/top-fx-news.html#id=SBA0000905878218084517604575588162528930920">Heading for the Exits</a></p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                               <p><a target="_self" href="/page/top-fx-news.html#id=SB124422420077263227">Maxs copyflow head</a></p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                               <p><a target="_self" href="/page/top-fx-news.html#id=SB10000905878218083472704574376690644613128">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </a></p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                               <p><a target="_self" href="/page/top-fx-news.html#id=SB10001424052748704869304575109260357455930">Societe Generale's Anne On Emerging Markets</a></p>
                            </li>
                        </ul> 
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="hidden" id="topNews_panel_other">
                    <div class="zippercontent" id="topNews_ticker_other">
                        <ul class="nav-inline arrows"><li class="prev"><a href="#prev"></a></li><li class="next"><a href="#next"></a></li></ul>
                        <ul class="newsItem">
                            <li>
                               <p><a target="_self" href="/page/top-news.html#id=SBA0000905878218084658104576313671111792858">Societe Generale's Anne On Emerging Markets</a></p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                               <p><a target="_self" href="/page/top-news.html#id=SB10000905878218084177704576096354110344310">Hawaii Feels 'Lost' Without Show</a></p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                               <p><a target="_self" href="/page/top-news.html#id=SB10001424052748704869304575109211904240490">Cisco's Gains Lift Tech Sector</a></p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                               <p><a target="_self" href="/page/top-news.html#id=SB10001424052748704706304575107532929516718">Nostalgia for New Deal Job Plan</a></p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                               <p><a target="_self" href="/page/top-news.html#id=SB121673131973850097">Credit Crisis Slams Wachoviane</a></p>
                            </li>
                        </ul> 
                    </div> 

                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="newstickermore ">
                        <div class="fxnewsmore">
                            <ul>
                                <li><P><a href="http://www.google.com" class="dulled">All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy</a></P></li>
                                <li><P><a href="">All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy</a></P></li>
                                <li><P><a href="">All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy</a></P></li>
                                <li><P><a href="">All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy</a></P></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="topnewsmore">
                            <ul>
                                <li><P><a href="">All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy</a></P></li>
                                <li><P><a href="">All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy</a></P></li>
                                <li><P><a href="">All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy</a></P></li>
                                <li><P><a href="">All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy</a></P></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Note - recently edited due to missing xhtml.

Comment: +1 for lots of info and code.  -0.33 for illegible headline.  :-)

Comment: I would really appreciate a better way to word the headline - I am very confused as to the best way to say what the exact issue is!

Answer (score 1):

Use the inspector in Chrome (the magnifier icon in the Elements tab of the developer tools).

Select the tool, then click on your link. It will select the element that is over your link that catch the clicks. You can debug from there, by inspecting the inline styles (applied with javascript) and the styles from the css, and the computed styles.

You can do the same thing with Firebug if you are more familiar with it.

Comment: Due to certificate issues I am unable to access the site in Chrome. I use Firebug on a daily basis but I am unfamiliar with how to determine what the active element is as you mention above.

Comment: *If you're speaking of the element select tool, unfortunately when I use that every time it selects the link that I am clicking on and its containers. Could you be a bit more specific or offer a more precise way to do what you are saying (or explain what you are saying if I am misunderstanding you a bit more?) Thank you for replying to my question!

Comment: Sorry, I am not very familiar with Firefox. But I just read your question again. Since the links actually are clickable and you say Firebug selected the link, the bug must come from JavaScript.